# How to update a div with form_tag with remote in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic, unobtrusive-javascript, jrails, remote-forms

I have the following code

```
<% form_tag  update_batting_order_tournament_path ,:complete => visual_effect(:appear, 'inning_update_success'), :method => :get, :remote => true do %>
```

basically I want to update a div

Inning Order Updated!

This is not working as I have written.  Any ideas of what the correct option is

Answer (score 0):

Just use <%= instead of <%.

```
   <%= form_tag  update_batting_order_tournament_path ,:complete => visual_effect(:appear, 'inning_update_success'), :method => :get, :remote => true do %>
```

For more info refer to 
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html#helpers-with-blocks